# Binary compatibility across an Ubuntu LTS release is guaranteed?

Tags: compatibility

User space binaries(not kernel modules) which are built on 14.04 base(14.04.0) LTS are guaranteed to work on other 14.04 point releases and their updates i.e. 14.04.1 + updates to 14.04.5+updates?   If binary compatibility is maintained across a particular(in our case 14.04), we want to build a package on 14.04 base and use the same on all point releases(14.04.1 to 14.04.5). Our binaries typically depend on few system libraries like libc, libgcc, libm etc.

```
root@UB1-14043-31925:/root# ldd binaryx
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbcbc0000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f7918297000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7918079000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7917e75000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7917c6d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7917969000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7917753000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f791738e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f791849c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7917088000)

root@UB1-14043-31925:/root# ldd binaryy
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe79b8d000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6566863000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6566645000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6566441000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6566239000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6565f35000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6565d1f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f656595a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6566a68000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6565654000)

root@UB1-14043-31925:/root# ldd binaryz
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe34165000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2ca4687000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2ca4483000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2ca427b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2ca3f77000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2ca3c71000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2ca3a5b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2ca3696000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2ca48a5000)

root@UB1-14043-31925:/root# ldd binarya
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff06dc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4fe8581000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4fe837d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4fe8175000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4fe7e71000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4fe7b6b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4fe7955000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4fe7590000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4fe879f000)
```

Comment: Could somebody please respond?